# Connect component to the store right in the component js file

Tags: reactjs, redux

In many tutorials I've seen people doing the following:

creating `RegistrationForm` file in the`components` folder:

```
const RegistrationForm= (props) => (
  <div className="registration-page">
    <Helmet>
      <title>NT SN | Registration</title>
    </Helmet>
    ... doing something
  </div>
)

export default RegistrationForm
```

and then In the `containers` folder they create the same file `RegistrationForm` and connect it to the `store`:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import RegistrationFormComponent from '../../components/RegistrationPage/RegistrationForm'

const RegistrationForm = connect(state => ({
  activeUser: state.activeUser
}), {})(RegistrationFormComponent)

export default RegistrationForm
```

Can I just `connect` my `component` to the `store` right in the `component` file ? If yes, what's the point of the `containers` folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can I just connect my component to the store right in the component file ?

> Yes you can

If yes, what's the point of the containers folder?

> If you connect your component in containers folder your result after
>   connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(yourcomponent) will not
>   be available for reuse. if you have separate file having connect
>   logic, you can reuse it across more than one dumbComponents

you container keeps data mapped to redux state and also actions. You can just simply call any dumbComponent with that container export and you get all the data and actions with it. The use case will be more obvious when you have different dumbcomponents watching and expecting same set of data and actions

Answer (score 2):

> Can I just connect my component to the store right in the component
>   file ?

Yes.

> If yes, what's the point of the containers folder?

It's just a way that some people like to organise their code in. The idea is that you separate presentational part of the component away from the "heavy lifting & logical" part of the component.

See [Presentational and Container Components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0)  article for the logic behind it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can organize your folders in a way you want. I currently work with two projects with different code structure. In one of them, I split folders by domain/features, not by container/components

Here's the good article about folders structure with lots of links: 
https://redux.js.org/docs/faq/CodeStructure.html

P.S. of course you can do so